# What happened to Nopperabo's entire face?

Tags: golden-kamui

A flashback of Noperabbo before he went to jail shows him looking pretty normal, like the average Human Being.
[image]
However, he presently looks like some form of Alien with literally no resemblance to his former self.

[image]
What exactly caused this drastically uncanny change in his facial appearance?